# MKLocalSearch (search.start)always goes in the error flow. (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been trying to learn swift for the past few days and just started my own project! As part of the project I wanted to show nearby cocktail bars on a map, I was able to find some nice info online and have been able to show a map with my current location. I also found info on how to find nearby locations: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch/request
Unfortunately this last one never seems to work, it just goes out of the function and does not return any locations, could anyone help me further? Below is the code of my viewcontroller with the function getNearbyLandmarks which doesn't work as intended.

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
private var landmarks: [Landmark] = [Landmark]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
  
    
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        render(location)
    }
}

func render(_ location: CLLocation){
    
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                            longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                                longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate,
                                    span: span)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.setRegion(region,
                      animated: true)
    
    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
    pin.coordinate = coordinate
    pin.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    self.getNearByLandmarks()
    updateAnnotations(from: mapView)
}



func mapView(_ mapViewIcon: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    var annotationView = mapViewIcon.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "custom")
    
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,
                                          reuseIdentifier: "custom")
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    }else{
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "User")
    
    return annotationView
}





private func getNearByLandmarks(){
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "coffee"
    request.region = mapView.region
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start{(response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                let mapItems = response.mapItems
                self.landmarks = mapItems.map{
                    Landmark(placemark: $0.placemark)
                }
            }
                
            
        }
    }

private func updateAnnotations(from mapView: MKMapView){
    let annotations = self.landmarks.map(LandmarkAnnotation.init)
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

}

Comment: "this last one never seems to work"  Where!?

Comment: I'm talking about the getNearbyLandmarks function, and in my explanation text I referred to the ios docx: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch/request

Comment: After a bit more testing, it only works when I reload my map 3 times, the first two times never seem to work. No clue why? Also, I am working in a simulator, could this give some problems?

Answer (score 0):

You call getNearByLandmarks, and then immediately try to update the annotations:

```
self.getNearByLandmarks()
updateAnnotations(from: mapView)
```

but getNearByLandmarks is asynchronous, and takes some time to complete. You need to update the annotations whenever `private var landmarks` changes, one way is to update it in all the places that set that, like where you say

```
   self.landmarks = mapItems.map{
            Landmark(placemark: $0.placemark)
        }
```

note you don't call updateAnnotations(from: mapView) there.

Or you could add a didSet property observer to landmarks itself so that updateAnnotations is called whenever it changes.